# Is there any way by which we can change the values of environment variables dynamically in an Angular 10 application?

Tags: angular, environment-variables, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-application, capacitor

I have an Angular application that currently has the same source code but with different environment based on whether the country is Canada or the US.
I have wrapped up the application using `Capacitor.js` to create mobile applications for iOS and Android.
Now I am stuck at a point where I need the same application to use Different Environment Variables based on User Selection (**Canada** or the **US**)
I need a way to integrate the above logic in the same mobile application source code, or otherwise, I'll have to create a separate mobile application for both countries.

Let me know if you know anyway or work around for this issue.

Comment: where did you stored environment variable right now ?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda I am storing it in the `environment.ts` file, which is being used by importing in multiple files.

Comment: do you know about `app_initializer` token in angular ?

Answer (score 0):

The environment replacement happens at build time, so you'd need different builds for different targets. You probably want a service with some logic to determine which logic you want. You could also change the property from the environment at runtime (for instance in the app initializer).